# Tips on Copying 3 Database files nearing 250 GB?

Tags: sql, files, large-data

We are upgrading from SQL Workgroup 2005 to SQL Standard 2012.   We have plenty of databases of smaller sizes that copied over with straight windows file copy in a reasonable time frame.   We have one database that is in 3 files, 53 GB, 93 GB and 100 GB respectively.   File copying of these files through the OS is taking forever.   No where near the gigabit network speeds, in fact it's around 40mbits per second on average.

The SQL 2005 system is on Windows Small Business Server 2003.
The SQL 2012 system is on Windows Standard Server 2012.

Any pointers would be appreciated.   I just tried using ESEUTIL but gained no speed.  I'm currently copying to a USB Western Digital Passport 1TB but that will take some time as well.

Comment: You used ESEUTIL on a SQL database? I've never heard of that before. Have you tried backing up the database to your USB drive and restoring to the new server from there?

Comment: Those speeds are diagnostically not good. I suspect something hinky is going on in your network stack.

Comment: @joeqerty This is where I read about trying ESEUTIL [link]http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/05/08/slow-large-file-copy-issues.aspx[link].

Comment: @sysadmin1138 Before attempting these copies, I used iperf between the two machines in question, both on a gigabit switch, each running a gigabit nic at gigabit speeds.  The iPerf tests showed allowed me to transfer 172 GB in 40 mins.  I suppose this wasnt a true representation since that was a direct TCP test, and that I should expect some overheard from Windows... but I thought I'd be a lot closer.